# Trying to retrieve the last letter of a String which includes spaces

Tags: java, string, substring, whitespace

Right, so I'm a little bit stuck trying to retrieve the last letter using .substring. If I input for example, "100C" it will work properly and the variable celOrFar will = "C". However, the user is supposed to insert a space after the number, but doing so will give me an incorrect result. "100 C" would give me "0" instead of C and "1234 5678C" would give me 4! I'm still a beginner with Java so any help is appreciated!

```
public static void stateOfWater() {     

    System.out.println("Enter a temperature followed by a space and C / F: ");
    String userInput = input.next();
    String celOrFar = userInput.substring(userInput.length()-1);

    String degreeString = userInput.trim();
    degreeString = degreeString.replace("C", "");
    degreeString = degreeString.replace("F", "");
    degreeString = degreeString.replace("f", "");
    degreeString = degreeString.replace("c", "");

    int degree = Integer.parseInt(degreeString);    

    if (celOrFar.equals("C")|| celOrFar.equals("c")) {          
        if (degree <= 0) {System.out.println("Your water is a solid at " +userInput);}          
        if (degree >= 100) {System.out.println("Your water is a gas at " +userInput);}      
        if (degree >0 && degree <100) {System.out.println("Your water is a liquid at " +userInput);}            
    }

    if (celOrFar.equals("F") || celOrFar.equals("f")) {         
        if (degree <= 32) {System.out.println("Your water is a solid at " +userInput);}         
        if (degree >= 212) {System.out.println("Your water is a gas at " +userInput);}          
        if (degree >32 && degree <212) {System.out.println("Your water is a liquid at " +userInput);}           
    }   
}
```

Comment: The scanner use space as separator, you should read the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanner.next` read character until it encounters a space. if you want to read the complete line including space then you need to use `nextLine`. see below.

```
public static void stateOfWater() {     

System.out.println("Enter a temperature followed by a space and C / F: ");
String userInput = input.nextLine(); // this will read the complete line including spaces.
String celOrFar = userInput.substring(userInput.length()-1);

String degreeString = userInput.trim();
degreeString = degreeString.replace("C", "");
degreeString = degreeString.replace("F", "");
degreeString = degreeString.replace("f", "");
degreeString = degreeString.replace("c", "");

int degree = Integer.parseInt(degreeString);    

if (celOrFar.equals("C")|| celOrFar.equals("c")) {          
    if (degree <= 0) {System.out.println("Your water is a solid at " +userInput);}          
    if (degree >= 100) {System.out.println("Your water is a gas at " +userInput);}      
    if (degree >0 && degree <100) {System.out.println("Your water is a liquid at " +userInput);}            
}

if (celOrFar.equals("F") || celOrFar.equals("f")) {         
    if (degree <= 32) {System.out.println("Your water is a solid at " +userInput);}         
    if (degree >= 212) {System.out.println("Your water is a gas at " +userInput);}          
    if (degree >32 && degree <212) {System.out.println("Your water is a liquid at " +userInput);}           
   }   
}
```